# Circular security.context when using templating. Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I have a problem, which I can't find the solution. I wrote my own security provider, that authorize user without saving them in any odb or orm. I tied authenticated users at the session and if the user has no session, I think, that he is not logged in. So, when I try to authenticate, I have the exception:

```
Circular reference detected for service "security.context", path: "security.firewall.map.context.main -> security.context -> security.authentication.manager -security.authentication.provider.wsse.main   -> wsse_provider ->  privatmarket.businessbundle.businessauth.model -business_account.service -> company_info.service -> templating -> debug.templating.engine.twig -> twig".
```

The error appears in this code:

```
    $body = $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('::XML-templates/company_info.xml.twig', array(
        'session' => $session,
        'ekb_id' => $ekbId
    ))->getContent();
```

And when I authenticate second time - all work fine.

If I write body as xml string - all work fine from first auth. I really don't understand what to do with this.

P.S. I read, that this problem was solve in version of Symfony 2.6. I use 2.3

Comment: try don't pass the session to the twig template and access directy in the twig with `app.session` as described in the [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#app). Hope this help.

Comment: No, it doesn't help. I'm not trying to access session in twig and I'm not pass session to twig. I'm just trying to create a service with parameter @security.context

Comment: Timed solution is remove twig templating from my model :(